# How can I get information into a hash, and format the output of this information in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, haml

example:

```
 % dl
  %dt Series:
  %dd 5GW00239
```

How can I do to show the beginning of the hash in the %dt and when you have the two points within the hash line under it and jump to show the "rest" in the %dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a hash that looks something like this:

```
series_hash = {"Series1:" => "5GW00239", "Series2:" => "ABCDEFG"}
```

If this is the case, then you need a HAML file like

```
- keys = series_hash.keys
- keys.each do |key|
    %dl
      %dt= key
      %dd= series_hash[key]
```

should result in

```
<dl>
    <dt>Series1:</dt>
    <dd>5GW00239</dd> 
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Series2:</dt>
    <dd>ABCDEFG</dd>
</dl>
```